# Some questions about linear operator in Brouwer degree.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, differential-topology, vector-analysis

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow R^n$ is $C^1$, $\Omega$ is bounded open subset of $R^n$.

And $f(x_0)=\theta$, $J_f(x_0)\ne 0$.$J_f$ is Jacobi of $f$, $\theta=(0,...,0)$.

Then ,how to show :

$f'(x_0)$ has bounded inverse.More detail, why $J_f(x_0)\ne 0$ make that $f'(x_0)$ has bounded inverse.

The more detail the better, thanks very much.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: This is (more or less) the statement of the inverse function theorem. Are you asking for a proof or how the above assertions are deduced from your version of the theorem? And what exactly is the connection to the Brouwer degree? Please specify your question.

Comment: @MaoWao  According to inverse function theorem , I think there is a inverse. About the "bounded", it seemly not be included  in  inverse function theorem . I want to know how the assertions are deduced.